# How to find the minimum of $x^2 + \frac{25}{x^2} + 3$ with proof based mathematics (no calculus)?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I have a question where this is this expression:

$x^2 + \frac{25}{x^2} + 3$ where $x > 0$

And you have to find the minimum value of this expression. However, you cannot use calculus, such as graphing etc. but only certain proof related expression i.e. arithmetic-geometric mean inequality and basic algebra. I am not too sure what next step there is to it. Thanks.

(Note: I have answered by own question, if anyone can verify that it is true or not, please clarify and I will fix it or mark another solution as correct).

Comment: Just apply AM-GM, or equivalent, would do.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what you mean by that, how exactly? Can you elaborate? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I think the selected answer (I choose) is actually *to an extent* wrong.

This is because, the proof cannot be concluded with:

$x^2 + \frac{25}{x^2} +3 \geq 13$

You actually need to find a number in which the equation is true at $13$. Therefore, you cannot start with the steps of an expressions being $\geq 0$ because you wouldn't be able to conclude which numbers can actually "reach" the minimum of $13$. Therefore, you use the AGM (Arithmetic-Geometric mean) inequality, where $a = x^2$ and $b = \frac{25}{x^2}$ and solve accordingly. Then with that, you can find the appropriate numbers which satisfy the equation and conclude the *proof correctly*.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \left( x - \frac{5}{x} \right)^2  \geq 0 $$
$$ x^2 - 10 + \frac{25}{x^2} \geq 0 $$
$$ x^2 + \frac{25}{x^2} \geq 10 $$
$$ x^2 + \frac{25}{x^2} +3 \geq 13 $$

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. However, I don't seem to get why you have -10 in the answer because I have 3. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your edit. I am just curious; would solving this type of proof come from practicing in proofs from general? Thanks.